# Pandas DF replacing none values with average of dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a pandas df and a collection of dictionaries.
I'm attempting to create a new column that has the value at that row indices with the value from the dictionary, and if that value is not in the dictionary replace that input with the average of the entire dictionary.

Currently my code looks like:

```
df_test["course_mean_time"] = df_test["Course"].apply(lambda x: Course_dict.get(x))
df_test.course_mean_time.fillna(mean(Course_dict[k] for k in Course_dict), inplace=True)
df_test['Horse_mean_time'] = df_test["Horse"].apply(lambda x: Horse_dict.get(x))
df_test.Horse_mean_time.fillna(mean(Horse_dict[k] for k in Horse_dict), inplace=True)
df_test['Dist_mean_time'] = df_test['Dist_M'].apply(lambda x: Dist_dict.get(x))
df_test.Dist_mean_time.fillna(mean(Dist_dict[k] for k in Dist_dict), inplace=True)
df_test['Jockey_mean_time'] = df_test['Jockey'].apply(lambda x: Jockey_dict.get(x))
df_test.Jockey_mean_time.fillna(mean(Jockey_dict[k] for k in Jockey_dict), inplace=True)
```

The course_mean_time code works correctly, but all code after that is replacing the None values with NaN values instead of the mean for the dictionary. I know the dictionaries have values in them and they are being called correctly, so I don't know why this would be occurring.
The output of the above code looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized where my mistake was.
The code,

```
mean(Course_dict[k] for k in Course_dict)
```

for example, returned a nan value.
The solution I found was instead to use:

```
Series([Course_dict[k] for k in Course_dict]).mean()
```